# Tire crack, requires replacing or not?

Tags: tires, mazda-3, cracking

This morning I noticed the following crack in the sidewall of my front tire. Wasn't sure if it was anything serious so I took it to the nearest tire shop and asked a couple of the guys working there if it needed replacement.

They said it's just superficial and there's nothing to worry about. Yet I'm not feeling too convinced, especially since what I've read online says that I should have it replaced.

Can anyone please confirm that this tire damage holds no risk so that I can stop worrying about it? Thanks in advance to you all.

[image: tire pic0]

[image: tire pic1]

[image: tire pic2]

Comment: I up voted your question, it's a very common misconception.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a cut to the sidewall of the tire where it meets the rim. Very dangerous to drive this way. Please change the tires immediately.

Let me know the previous tire profile, I'll recommend a good all round tire for your needs.

FYI: this may rip open any time.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll go get it changed ASAP. I'd throw in a pic showing the depth but it's already nightfall here.
I'll keep ye posted and choose the answer once the issue is resolved. Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: @ NightSpark What is the current tire profile?

Comment: 215 45 ZR17 91W, currently using TOYO tires

Comment: Added pics to show the depth of the damage

Comment: @Nightspark Thank you for the snapshots. Overall these tires are good: https://www.walmart.com/ip/BF-Goodrich-g-FORCE-COMP-2-A-S-Tire215-45ZR17XL-91W/44658621

Comment: The more speed bumps and pot holes that are hit at good speeds will tear that rubber around, if you notice where the letter 'S' is under your finger on the left side, it's starting to tear deep.

Comment: How many did you order?

Comment: Hey pal, any update?

Comment: How are those new tires?